# Error on reading image data from SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a windows application and store image in database.

My database is `Sql server2008 R2`. On insertion image successfully saved to DB, i tried data types `image` and `Varbinary(MAX)`. In both case on retrieve image it show the error "Parameter is Not Valid". Anyone tell me a solution for this? Is there any change will do in sql server?.

This is my code for retrieve image,

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
     byte[] img_arr1 = (byte[])dr["img"];
     MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(img_arr1);
     ms1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);    
     pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms1);    
}
```

**Code UPDATE from comments**:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\imgs.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=true"); 
con1.Open(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select img from demo1", con1);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

if (dr.Read()) 
{ 
   byte[] img_arr1 = (byte[])dr["img"]; 
   MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(img_arr1); 
   ms1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
   pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms1);
}
```

Comment: First recommendation is to use `using` statement for sqldatareader. Secondly you have to show your command parameters.

Comment: Show your `SqlCommand` and any associated parameters. Also, depending on what your command looks like, if you're only returning a single object, you could also use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`, which will return the first column of the first row.  Seeing `if (dr.Read())` as the only use of the reader always strikes me as a waste.

Comment: SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\imgs.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=true");
            con1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select img from demo1", con1);
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {   byte[] img_arr1 = (byte[])dr["img"];
                    MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(img_arr1);
                    ms1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms1);}

Comment: There is no where clause in the query. How many records you expect to be returned?

Comment: ya only 1 set of data is saved in db.so no need of where condition

Comment: I tried almost all codes,but there is no change in that error **Parameters not valid**.Is there any damage in sql server???